# Is it possible to show only certain messages to users in MQTT topics?

Tags: mqtt

My goal is to extend an HTTPS REST API platform with an MQTT bus. I am trying to figure out what the best way is to go about this.

**Topic Example**:
I have an HTTPS REST API that contains the following end-points.
1) `/files/{fileId}`
2) `/files`

If I want to restrict users based on fileId's, it is easy for topic 1. If somebody is allowed to see this file, they can subscribe, otherwise they can not.

Now my question is about the second topic. Would it be possible, to publish to `/files` but only show subscribers the data they are allowed to see?

**Message Example:**
I publish these messages to `/files`

```
{
    "fileName": "Test.txt",
    "fileId": 123456,
    "Author": "Bert",
    "Content": "Hello World"
}
------
{
    "fileName": "Test2.txt",
    "fileId": 654321,
    "Author": "Hank",
    "Content": "Foo Bar"
}
```

Bert and Hank are both subscribed to `/files` but they are only allowed to see their own files (Bert = 123456, Hank = 654321).

**UPDATE**:
In [this](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices) artice the topic starts with `myhome` etc. This might be the same example as above. If I publish to `myhome`, how can I know it is only this user when I have multiple users.

Comment: Are there any other concepts, other than users? Are there groups of people who all have the same permissions too? Setting permissions may depend on the broker you choose, do you have one in mind? Rather than mapping the MQTT paths directly to the REST paths, you may be better publishing to  users/hank/file_changes

Comment: No, this is the only concept. What I am trying to understand is how to do this best. For example, would be username / client-id be an option? Ie, can I send something to a topic _and_ to a username / client-id?

Comment: Also see the updated question...

Comment: Please note, MQTT topics should not start with a leading '/'

Comment: thanks, updated the question ;-)

Comment: MQTT topics *can* start with a leading `/`, but it adds in an unnecessary level of hierarchy. I agree with the sentiment from @hardillb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ACL schemes for MQTT tend to be based purely username and access to a topic (or wildcard topic).

Messages are published to a topic, there is no way to specify anything more (e.g. username or client id).

Having to do message payload inspection to determine if a subscriber is able to see a specific message would have a huge impact on performance. Also as there is no prescribed message payload format (you can send any byte array payload) coming up with a way to specify a which parts of the message to filter on would be difficult.

You may be able to implement something like this by modifying a open source brokers, but I doubt it would be easy.

Comment: Thanks @hardillb, I'm trying to relate your answer to this article: http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices The article contains `myhome` as a topic. But I assume that multiple users can subscribe to `myhome` but see different things.

Comment: No, all users subscribed to `myhome` will see all the same messages

Comment: ooo. In that case, would the topic: `{secrect_access_token}/myhome` be a valid way of setting this up? (and: `{secrect_access_token}/myhome/groundfloor`, etcetera)

Comment: Yes, you can limit access with a scheme like that

Comment: Aha, and last question :-) would it be secure? If I would use SSL? So no username/password but only a token in the topic?

Comment: No, you should use a Username/Password as well so the user can be matched to a ACL to prevent somebody just subscribing to `#` and seeing everything

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks very convoluted. Maybe we have an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) case here.  You seem to want to [ab]use a public-subscriber mechanism as a point-to-point mechanism over a non-secure (broadcast) network, like a WiFi without encryption or an ethernet without switches but hubs instead.

In that case you may want to use endpoints as topics (networknode{1, 2, ...}), to address individual computers, and if the answers are not to be seen by everyone, you will have to encrypt them.  And you then need a mechanism for distributing the keys.

Or maybe you just want to use plain HTTPS.  MQTT has been a huge step forward for the IoT world, but it is not the panacea.
On the other hand, why is the file ID not part of the topic?